# My laptop stole the internet

Tags: wireless, networking

I have an HP DM4 laptop running Ubuntu 13.04 (although i've noticed this on 12.04 and 12.10). When I am connected to the WiFi at home none of my housemates are able to get decent connection. They can connect but not use the internet. I've noticed it a number of other places including hotspots in motels etc.

It's not a problem for me but I am becoming increasingly unpopular at home!!

I have the Broadcom STA Wireless driver installed and am using it.

Let me know if I can give any more useful information.

Thanks

Comment: This could be a driver issue. Someone has the same issue with the same laptop here: [Laptop blocking other computers on home WiFi routers](http://askubuntu.com/q/281035/52726). From the comments there, someone managed to fix it by using another wireless driver (http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2131244). Also, it's worth checking the answer here first: [Ubuntu 13.04 causes other pcs internet to be slow?](http://askubuntu.com/q/283511/52726). Disable the proprietary driver by going to the "Software & Updates" application, and go to the last tab "Additional Drivers".

Comment: Which one? Which steps did you follow?

Comment: I followed the steps in this thread (http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2131244) blacklisting the various broadcom drivers and enabling the correct kernel module.

Comment: Since the steps in the thread are not documented here on AskUbuntu, and the person that asked the other question hasn't visited for quite some time, I'll answer your question, and you can mark it as accepted to indicate to others that it has been solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**From here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2131244**

1. Open up the file `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` with your favorite text editor, and add the following to the end of the file:

   ```
   blacklist bcm43xxblacklist b43
   blacklist b43legacy
   blacklist bcma
   blacklist ndiswrapper
   blacklist wl
   ```
2. Open up the file `/etc/modules` with your favorite text editor, and add the following at the end of the file:

   ```
   brcmsmac
   ```

   Alternatively, you can type `sudo sh -c "echo 'brcmsmac' >> /etc/modules"` in a terminal to do this in one go.
3. Reboot the machine.

Answer (score 1):

### This has happened to me a few times.

It usually is a problem with the router, not your wi-fi.

1. Unplug the router from the power outlet and wait 20seconds before
   plugging in again.
2. Reboot your PC also just to be sure.

### Another problem can be an IP conflict

So you have to `reserve a dedicated internal IP address` for your computer.

1. Access your router using the internal IP (usually 192.168.0.1 if
   using a DLink device but it may vary)
2. Use your user and password (usually user:"admin" and pasword:"admin"
   or blank)
3. Search for "Network settings" and wherever you notice a table of
   MACaddresses and IP numbers, you should find a button to "reserve"
   IPs.
4. Reserve the IPs of devices you recognize as yours and your roomates (so each one has it's own IP and there should be no conflict).

`NOTE: Instrucctions are different depending on the make and model of your router.`

And that's that.